# Unable to open Word template using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, templates, ms-word, vsto

I'm creating a VSTO application that reads and updates text in a Word template, and saves it in another file. The problem is I can't open any Word template (.dotx).

When I click the button in the ribbon to trigger the open template event, it's simply not giving any error or warning message, it just makes Word freeze for some seconds and not giving any return. It does not show any template, just a plain white page like when you create a new document.

Here is my code, note that the `startuppath` variable is the result of trying manipulate path.

```
string startupPath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
Debug.Print(startupPath);
startupPath = startupPath + "\\templateKoding\\leTemplateKoding.dotx";

Debug.Print("new path : "+startupPath);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = word.Documents.Add(@"C:\Users\futtbucker\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Koding\Koding\templateKoding\leTemplateKoding.dotx");
```

Comment: in that code, startupPath is not used. my plan is to pass startupPath as argument into Add()

Answer (score 1):

to open use word.Documents.Open